# Bad Loading/Creation of UI

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch

I created My **iPad** application. It is work fine and properly. 
But i have issue about bad creation of `UI`. My application take so much time for create `UI`.

> **For Your Information :** I already Done Design, I have only issue related to **Loading/creation of UI**  and I put here only one PLOT for better Understanding of my Question. **Actually all PLOTS are created DYNAMICALLY.**

**For More Understanding See My Image:**

[image]

**My Image say that**

**PLOT** is Main View `(UIView)` that Contain All of The SubViews That Display in Image.

- Here **Plot-1** is Title it is UILabel
- column 3 is also title (UILabel) That display selected column, Here if you select column 1 then title is column 1, if you select column 2 then title is column 2, and so more....

**Colomn 1, Column 2, And Column 3** all are is `UIView` that **SubView** of mainView *(PLOT - 1)*

- Here Each **Column has 5** `UITextField` *(doted line is `UITextFiled`)* and `UITextField` is SubView of its own **Column**.

**So Here ALL,, PLOTS and COLUMNS and UITEXTFIELDS are Dynamic it is not Fix.**

I already done its Design But it is generated issue of loading when **PLOT is More Then 40 above**..

In my application, I Created all the Design of **UI** By using **for Loop**. So it is bad for me when PLOT is More Then 40 above**. But if **PLOT IS Under 40** then its Work very well.

AnyBody have another option/suggestion that create **UI** without using  **for Loop** ????

Please Help Me on This Issue.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by " generated issue of loading when PLOT is More Then 40 above.." ?

How many plots do you have?

Comment: are you creating 40 plots (UIViews) and loading them all into memory at the same time? Why not one at a time? Only create the plot that is being displayed...

Comment: @Cashew- thanks for replay PLOT number is Base on two value that inserted by use... for example if value1 = 5 and value2 = 8 that PLOT is multiplied by Value1 and Value 2. It Means PLOT is (5*8) = 40

Answer (score 0):

Why not using UITableView/UICollectionView? - It's much faster and memory efficient.

The only thing you should take care of, it's saving the user inputs in some array so you can display it again when needed.

Comment: UITableView/UICollectionView Not Use because all the PLOT Are Arrange in Horizontally and also how can i change column title that i selected and also how can i got uitextField Values etc. it is more critical or may be not possible to create this type of design..